# get sum of multiple values by months in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have table with query :

```
   SELECT DATENAME(Month,TOPUP.tu_timestamp) AS MonthName, TM.terminal_name, 
   CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(TOPUP.tu_credit - NC.initial_bal, TOPUP.tu_credit) / 
   TOPUP.currency_rate, 2) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS 
   Top_Up_Value                       
   FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_top_up_logs AS TOPUP 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal_user AS TU ON TOPUP.terminal_user_id = 
   TU.terminal_user_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_currency AS CR ON TOPUP.currency_id = CR.currency_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_cuid AS CU ON TOPUP.cu_id = CU.cu_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_card_role AS CO ON CO.id = CU.card_role_id             
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account AS UA ON UA.terminal_user_id = 
   TU.terminal_user_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal AS TM ON TM.terminal_id = UA.terminal_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map AS MA ON MA.tu_log_id = 
   TOPUP.tu_log_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs AS NC ON 
   MA.nc_log_id = NC.nc_log_id
   WHERE (ISNULL(TOPUP.tu_credit - NC.initial_bal, TOPUP.tu_credit) > 0)
   and YEAR(TOPUP.tu_timestamp) = '2017'
   AND month(TOPUP.tu_timestamp) = 1
   AND TM.terminal_id = 7
   GROUP BY TOPUP.tu_log_id,DATENAME(Month,TOPUP.tu_timestamp), 
   TM.terminal_name, 
   TOPUP.tu_credit, NC.initial_bal, TOPUP.currency_rate, CU.card_type_id;

   MonthName          Terminal name         Top Up Value
  ------------------------------------------------------
    January            Terminal 1               100
    January            Terminal 1               200     
    January            Terminal 3               150
     Feb               Terminal 1               250
     Feb               Terminal 1               160
     March             Terminal 2               120
     March             Terminal 3               100
```

and i would like to have total sums of top up value according to months which look like this:

```
    MonthName       Top Up Value
  -----------------------------------
    January            450              
    February           410
    March              220
    -----
    Dec
```

as i am beginner in sql , i dont have idea how to do it. Really need help on these. Thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Group by monthname and sum the top up value?

Comment: The `mysql` and `tsql` tags are, as a rule, incompatible. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT DATENAME(Month,TOPUP.tu_timestamp) AS MonthName,  
  SUM(CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(TOPUP.tu_credit - NC.initial_bal, TOPUP.tu_credit) / 
  TOPUP.currency_rate, 2) AS decimal(18, 2))) AS 
  Top_Up_Value                       
  FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_top_up_logs AS TOPUP 
 INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal_user AS TU ON TOPUP.terminal_user_id = 
  TU.terminal_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your group by statement, the result you posted is displaying lesser number of columns then what you have in your query. Tweak it around and you will get your results

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT DATENAME(Month,TOPUP.tu_timestamp) AS MonthName,  
   SUM(CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(TOPUP.tu_credit - NC.initial_bal, TOPUP.tu_credit) / 
   TOPUP.currency_rate, 2) AS decimal(18, 2))) AS 
   Top_Up_Value                       
   FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_top_up_logs AS TOPUP 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal_user AS TU ON TOPUP.terminal_user_id = 
   TU.terminal_user_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_currency AS CR ON TOPUP.currency_id = CR.currency_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_cuid AS CU ON TOPUP.cu_id = CU.cu_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_card_role AS CO ON CO.id = CU.card_role_id             
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account AS UA ON UA.terminal_user_id = 
   TU.terminal_user_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbo.cdf_terminal AS TM ON TM.terminal_id = UA.terminal_id 
   INNER JOIN   dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map AS MA ON MA.tu_log_id = 
   TOPUP.tu_log_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs AS NC ON 
   MA.nc_log_id = NC.nc_log_id
   WHERE (ISNULL(TOPUP.tu_credit - NC.initial_bal, TOPUP.tu_credit) > 0)
   and YEAR(TOPUP.tu_timestamp) = '2017'
   AND month(TOPUP.tu_timestamp) = 1
   AND TM.terminal_id = 7
   GROUP BY DATENAME(Month,TOPUP.tu_timestamp)
```

Comment: thanks @john.. you solved my problem. really appreciate!